# How to run pruned node?

Tags: nodes

Is this possible with Ethereum?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the different options on syncing with `geth`

- "Full" Sync: Gets the block headers, the block bodies, and validates every element from genesis block.
- Fast Sync: Gets the block headers, the block bodies, it processes no transactions until current block - 64(*). Then it gets a snapshot state and goes like a full synchronization.
- Light Sync: Gets only the current state. To verify elements, it needs to ask to full (archive) nodes for the corresponding tree leaves.

Light sync is execute with `geth --light` and it is likely what you are looking for.

Comment: To add to this, here is an article that gives a great in-depth explanation of the various combinations of sync modes and associated sync-time and storage requirements: https://dev.to/5chdn/the-ethereum-blockchain-size-will-not-exceed-1tb-anytime-soon-58a

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what u r using for ethereum. The --light option is mandatory in newer versions of geth and parity. This will probably be the closet to pruning u can get.